# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression => EntityShaperExpression:

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I am getting this error on this line of code

```
        var attachment = await _context.Attachments
                            .Where(a => list.Any(i => i.Id == a.Id))
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Although the error is fixed when I change my code to

```
        var attachment = _context.Attachments
                            .ToList()
                            .Where(a => list.Any(i => i.Id == a.Id))
                            .ToList();
```

Does anyone have any idea on what is going on exactly here?

Comment: Post the full exception. What EF version are you using? What type is `list` ?

Comment: In the first case u use Linq to Entities and this involves in converting your linq expression to a SQL statement and in the second one u already bring from DB the list of items (Attachments.ToList()) and apply over it Linq to Objects.

Comment: EF Core, supports only `Contains` with local collection.

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv , you are right, I would change my query and would use `Contains` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you received suggests that `Entity Framework` couldn't translate this `LINQ` query into a valid `SQL` query, and that's why you got the exception.
The second approach works because it retrieves all the data from the Attachments table into memory first (using the `ToList()` method), and then applies the filtering using `LINQ` to Objects in memory.
This approach is generally less efficient if you have a large amount of data in the `Attachments` table because you are loading all records into memory.

You can do:

```
 var listOfIds = list.Select(item => item.Id);
 var attachmentS = await _context.Attachments
                            .Where(a => listOfIds.Contains(a.Id))
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Is there any way I can make it efficient, because I would have a lot of entries in the `Attachment` table

Comment: @AkshatSparrow updated answer, pls check

Comment: Thanks @BasilKosovan, I get it know EF Core supports only `Contains` with local collection.

Answer (score 0):

> Because the filter can't be applied in the database, all the data
> needs to be pulled into memory to apply the filter on the client.
> Based on the filter and the amount of data on the server, client
> evaluation could result in poor performance. So Entity Framework Core
> blocks such client evaluation and throws a runtime exception.

You can  have a look at [Unsupported client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#unsupported-client-evaluation) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the async LINQ query in your first code has nothing to do with the error. I think the root cause is that the `.where` LINQ method should be applied to an IQueryable object. Though should first see the compile time error.